# SAML TAI SSO with WebSphere Portal Server 7.0 excepts user in registry

Tags: saml-2.0, jaas, websphere-portal

We have Salesforce as IDP, WebSphere Portal v7.0 as SP. Our users are only available in Salesforce. From IBM, we came to know that Portal 7.0.0.2 does not support non availability of user in registry in terms of SAML whereas this feature is supported in WebSphere Portal 8 and 8+. SAML TAI happens properly, means any application deployed on WAS, SSO happens properly. Problem arises when we try to access WebSphere Portal. We get an error message that unable to find the user ID, even though it is available in the Subject.Now as a workaround, we need to create a user in Portal registry once SAML response is received. HAs anyone create a user on the fly in Portal registry through TAI or JAAS modules ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the User identities within the UserManagement system. WebSphere calls it VMM. It provides a pluggable infrastructure where you can trust the external users.

The function you have in Portal 8 and 8.5 had been developed first as an add on for Portal 7. Below is the link to it.

[OpenID WebSphere Portal v7](https://greenhouse.lotus.com/plugins/plugincatalog.nsf/assetDetails.xsp?action=editDocument&documentId=6B27E3494B12ACF28525787700512421)

Comment: Hi Stefan, But in our case it is not OpenID. We have SAML Web Browser based Authentication basically WAS TAI. Open ID as far as I remember has transient user functionality which is only available on WPS 8 and WPS 8.5, please correct me If I am wrong. Do you have any refernce code where VMM is able to trust external users ?

Comment: Sorry it came not clear. This package contains the component for transient users. Even if you do not use OpenID that's what would help you. You can install the transient user using the commands provided with the package linked above. 
But you could build your own VMM adapter and virtual act as a userrepository for the users provided by your SAML endpoint http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/zones/portal/proddoc/dw-w-userrepository/